# How to display different values in every loop of repeater of Advance Custom Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am Designing wordpress page with design of a image block with a  text on over it. but that design is repeated 6 times in my page, so i have used the advance custom field repeater  to repeat that image block for 6 times.
but now the issue is I want a new copy of text when i hover on each image.
as I used Jquery,  as my class name for the image block is same so when i hover on any of the boxes all the box content gets changed. i want on which box i hover only that content should change.

```
$(".services-block").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(".wrap-content-services").hide();
            $(".overlay-content-services").show();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(".wrap-content-services").show();`enter code here`
            $(".overlay-content-services").hide();
        }
    });
```

Html Structure of custom field

```
<?php if (have_rows('services_content')): ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php while (have_rows('services_content')): the_row() ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 services-block">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_sub_field('services_image'), 'full'); ?>
            <div class="wrap-content-services">
                <?php the_sub_field('services__overlay_content'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-content-services">
                <?php the_sub_field('services__hover_content'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Would help to provide output html not server code if the issue is client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JQuery to something like:

```
$(".services-block").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find(".wrap-content-services").hide();
        $(this).find(".overlay-content-services").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find(".wrap-content-services").show();`enter code here`
        $(this).find(".overlay-content-services").hide();
    }
});
```

`$(".wrap-content-services").hide();` will hide all elements with a class of .wrap-content-services